# Android hdpi splash screen, need explanation

Tags: android, size, screen, resolution, hdpi

I dont understand why my Nexus 7 has a 1920×1200 pixels resolution, but I should only use a 800-480px image to make a splash screen, its what I have been reading on internet for hdpi screen.

Why not use a 1920×1200 pixel image, theres is clearly something I dont understand. I know not every hdpi screens have this resolution, but wouldnt it look bad on my Nexus 7 if I used a 800-480px image ?

Im probably missing something here !?

Thanks in advance for your precious answers.

Comment: Don't use full screen backgrounds, to avoid memory leaks.